# Decimating Non-Uniform large time-series data

Tags: filters, python, time-series, scipy, nonuniform

I'm working with accelerometer data that is sampled at a non-uniform rate.  There are major gaps in the data. Below is a scatter plot of the data

[image]

I can also give a sense of the frquencies at which the data is sampled. 
 Below is a plot of the frequency distribution.  [image: Frequency Histogram]

As can be seen, the majority of the data comes in at 128Hz, with some at 100Hz, and then a range of other values.  Below I show a histogram that is created by collecting the time difference between samples.  The x-axis shows the different time steps, and the y-axis shows the incident number.

[image]

What I want to do is to decimate this data down to 1Hz.  What is best practice for this?  My understanding is that I would:

1) Interpolate up to say 128Hz first using cubic splines.
2) Apply a Hemming or Butterworth low pass filter.
3) Downsample by keeping every 128th point.

Issues: When I interpolate using cubicsplines, I get enormous values during the stretches in which there is a major gap in the data.  I could potentially mask for these gaps.

I'm working in python and have been looking at the scipy library to handle this.  I know Pandas has .resample().interpolate(), but it seems too memory intensive and slow.  The data takes up about 40gigs of memory.  Any insight or thoughts would be super appreciated.  Thanks friends!!

Comment: Can you talk a little bit more about what is depicted in this diagram and how was it created?

Comment: Yes.  The data shown is a histogram of the number of samples collected per second.  The x-axis is the number of samples per second, and the y-axis shows the incident number for the different frequencies.  All i did was group by second and count the number of rows I had for each second grouping.

Comment: Do you have time stamps for each sample?

Comment: Yes I have timestamps for each sample

Comment: OK, then, could you please do a histogram of the sample-to-sample intervals? This will give us the distribution of the sampling period. You can then decide for a better $Fs$. I would suggest that you treat "long gaps" as separate signals (possibly refering to the same "session", but still separate time series).

Comment: Ok I added that plot

Comment: Thank you, that is great. Can you please clarify what you mean by "...decimate this data down to 1 Hz"? What exactly is this 1 Hz?

Comment: Well the data is sampled irregularly at about 120Hz frequency.  I would like to downsample to 1Hz frequency.

Comment: This does not clarify things though. What is this 1Hz? 120Hz means that the time between samples is 1/120 seconds. What does this 1Hz mean? Where does it come into play? Are you saying that you want to slow down the waveform 120 times its original sampling frequency?

Comment: Yes I want to slow it down 120 times.

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't bother interpolating at all. You want to downsample by factor 128 anyway, so from that point of view, your raw data is already a good approximation of being uniformly sampled at 128Hz. Just go with low pass filtering and downsampling and you should be good. Try it on a small fraction of the data, to get an idea of the error you introduce by this approximation, my gut feeling says, it will be acceptable, i.e. small compared to the accelerometer error. If actual time span does matter, calculate the average sampling rate and use this value instead of 128Hz.

For handling large data sets with limited RAM, I would opt for generators in python (`yield` instead of `return`) This way, there is no need to keep all the data in memory, you just "stream" the data from file to file in (overlapping and  windowed) chunks of appropriate size.

Comment: Thank you.  May I ask what to do with large gaps of NaN's in my data?  I'm fine with interpolating away small gaps, but my data contains several larger chunks (in time space).  Do I need to filter each chunk individually?  Can a simply scipy lfilter handle NaNs?  Thanks :)

Comment: Just set the NaNs to Zero or the last valid value, your call.

Comment: Will that not create artifacts in my data?  What I imagine is as follows:
1) Create a mask for these gaps
2) Set the NaNs to zero
3) Filter
4) Apply the mask to reset those values back into NaNs

Is that what you imagine?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally resampling data that is non-uniformly sampled and/or contains non-valid samples is an interesting task.

If the downsampling ratio is large compared to the maximum (or average) sampling interval, you can possibly use a simple method. Take some average of a neighbourhood.

For a filtering approach, designing a continuous domain filter with some cutoff frequency that you sample at the offsets of input sample times vs desired output sample, normalize with number of input samples might work.